# How to tar certain file types in all subdirectories?

Tags: linux, tar

I want to tar and all .php and .html files in a directory and its subdirectories. If I use

`tar -cf my_archive *`

it tars all the files, which I don't want. If I use

`tar -cf my_archive *.php *.html`

it ignores subdirectories. How can I make it tar recursively but include only two types of files?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

`find ./someDir -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" | tar -cf my_archive -T -`

Comment: @DeeDee Are there any limitations on the number of files, etc.?

Comment: @DeeDee - no, what I meant was you don't need the parens!

Comment: @user1566515 There may be some filesystem limit or overall space limit which would put an upper limit on your tar file. That entirely depends on your own system. Otherwise, the piping will essentially create the tar file on-the-fly, so you won't be constrained by file number or size.

Comment: Thanks! ...  how to add more than 2 conditions / kind of file?

Comment: @gluuke use `-o -name [pattern]` for each new condition

Comment: @DeeDee : I am sorry, for some reason I am obtaining `find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]`

Answer (score 28):

If you're using `bash` version > 4.0, you can exploit `shopt -s globstar` to make short work of this:

```
shopt -s globstar; tar -czvf deploy.tar.gz **/Alice*.yml **/Bob*.json
```

this will add all .yml files that starts with Alice from any sub-directory and add all .json files that starts with Bob from any sub-directory.

Comment: The only answer that just uses tar, the best answer IMO.

Comment: Despite the impression  by glob '**' for directory, this command does not execute recursively (any sub-sub-folders)

Comment: @Eddie ** should work. may be there is something different with your parameters. Also check if there is any space in folder name that you pass in the command line. If not, can you paste your actual command ?

Comment: '**' is evaluated by the shell before reaching the command and it only seen as 2 independent * which resolves to 0 or characters, it has no recursive functionality to span directories http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Comment: @eddie yes it is evaluated by shell, though bash > 4.0 has a `shopt -s globstar` option, so the answer is correct and is actually the best one

Comment: `-bash: /usr/bin/tar: Argument list too long`
The expansion happens before being passed to tar and fails for large numbers of files.

Comment: @dmitry_podyachev solution below works well, using find to generate a list of files, then `tar -czf file.tar -T files.txt` to tar the files named in `files.txt`.

Answer (score 22):

One method is:

```
tar -cf my_archive.tar $( find -name "*.php" -or -name "*.html" )
```

There are some caveats with this method however:

1. It will fail if there are any files or directories with spaces in them, and
2. it will fail if there are so many files that the maximum command line length is full.

A workaround to these could be to output the contents of the find command into a file, and then use the "-T, --files-from FILE" option to tar.

Comment: 1) By "fail" do you mean the files with spaces will be skipped or the tar archive will not be created? 2) I have about 100K files. Is that over the maximum command line length?

Comment: 1. It will create the archive, but it will report missing files.
2. That will be too long, I expect.

Given this, you'd be best using a method like @DeeDee suggests below, it'll work around these problems quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

This will handle paths with spaces:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" -exec tar uvf myarchives.tar {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy with zsh:

```
tar cvzf foo.tar.gz **/*.(php|html)
```

Comment: Did you mean `-czvf`?

Comment: The `-` is optional with `tar`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to produce a **zipped** tar file (`.tgz`) and want to avoid problems with **spaces** in filenames:

```bash
find . \( -name \*.php -o -name \*.html \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cvzf my_archive.tgz
```

The `-print0` “primary” of `find` separates output filenames using the NULL (`\0`) byte, thus playing well with the `-0` option of `xargs`, which appends its (NULL-separated, in this case) input as arguments to the command it precedes.

The parentheses around the two `-name` primaries are needed, because otherwise the `-print0` would only output the filenames of the second `-name` (there is no implied printing if `-print` or `-print0` is present, and these only have an effect if they are evaluated).

If you need to **skip** some filenames or directories (e.g., the `node_modules` directory if you work with Node.js), prepend one or more `-prune` primaries like this:

```bash
find . -name skipThisName -prune -o \
  -name skipThisOtherName -prune -o \
  \( -name \*.php -o -name \*.html \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cvzf my_archive.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a file

```
find . \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" \) -print > files.txt
```

Then use the file as input to tar, use -I or -T depending on the version of tar you use

Use h to copy symbolic links

```
tar cfh my.tar -I files.txt
```

Comment: You mean `-T files.txt`, not `-I files.txt`, but otherwise, this is great for large numbers of files where expansion of `*` or `**` exceeds the shell limit.

Answer (score 0):

`find ./ -type f -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" -printf '%P\n' |xargs tar -I 'pigz -9' -cf target.tgz`

for multicore or just for one core:

`find ./ -type f -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" -printf '%P\n' |xargs tar -czf target.tgz`