# issue with the tar file to excude some files and rar only required files in the folder with same structure

Tags: shell, linux-kernel

hi i have a requirement like the following

`|
|------bar/
    |--file.pl
    |---FILE1.FILE2.FILE3.TXT
    |---FILE4.FILE5.FILE6.TXT
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   |---file1_file2.log
    |   |---file2_file1.log
    |
    |---subdir2/
        |---image1_image2.log
        |---image2_image1.log`

i am using the following command.

tar cvzf bar/  x.tar

and the output i am getting is as follows

`|
|------bar/
    |--file.pl
    |---FILE1.FILE2.FILE3.TXT
    |---FILE4.FILE5.FILE6.TXT
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   |---file1_file2.log
    |   |---file2_file1.log
    |
    |---subdir2/
        |---image1_image2.log
        |---image2_image1.log`

but i want the output like the following.i want to exclude .pl and i want only x.x.x.TXT and .LOG to be tar.

`|
|------bar/
    |
    |---FILE1.FILE2.FILE3.TXT
    |---FILE4.FILE5.FILE6.TXT
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   |---file1_file2.log
    |   |---file2_file1.log
    |
    |---subdir2/
        |---image1_image2.log
        |---image2_image1.log`

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `--exclude=*.pl` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ tar cvzf x.tar bar/ --exclude=*.pl
```

From man page:

```
--exclude=PATTERN
   exclude files, given as a PATTERN
```

Comment: this command is working fine from the command line while i use it in the shell script is not working and also i am getting error

Comment: Can you post the error message. I think there must be some special char in your pattern. You need to escape it using escape char '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731603/how-to-tar-certain-file-types-in-all-subdirectories).

```
find ./someDir -name "*.log" -o -name "*.TXT" | tar -cf my_archive -T -
```

Comment: This might break,, as some other files might be there with some other extension.

Comment: It will not care about the other and will only find "*.log" and "*.TXT" file. Have you tested it @pRAShANT??

Comment: My point is, that yes it might not be wrong (though I am skeptical that it would work) but it only gives limited functionality. What if, there are many other files also present and I dont know of their extension. So how to handle this case.

Comment: One fix can be, find the files using "find . ! -name *.pl", this will work and give all other files except *.pl

Comment: Read the question first he only need ".log" and ".TXT" file and he doesn't care about other files Sir.