# How to compress files with specified suffix in subdirectory？

Tags: linux

For example, current directory is `/A/B/`, some scripts whose suffixes are `.py` and `.sh` in `/A/B/C/`,`/A/B/C/D/` and `/A/B/E/`.

How to generate such a compressed file which has the structure of directories and contains the python /shell scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find with your compression, e.g.:

```
zip outfile -r `find . -name '*.py'` `find . -name '*.sh'`
```

Answer (score 1):

find ./someDir -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" | tar -cf my_archive -T -

as seen here in a question very similar to yours.
[How to tar certain file types in all subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731603/how-to-tar-certain-file-types-in-all-subdirectories)